# Is it possible to take the results of a SELECT and feed them into a VALUES clause?

Tags: sql, database, select, insert

For Example, is there any way to do something like the following:

```
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(SELECT x FROM table1 WHERE x > 5 LIMIT 4)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove VALUES and the brackets:

```
INSERT INTO table2 SELECT x FROM table1 WHERE x > 5 LIMIT 4
```

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable(column1, column2, column5)
SELECT x as column1, y as column2, a as column5
FROM differentTable
WHERE ....
```